Flipped histogram with count going left rather than right
I need to graph a flipped histogram (i.e. count on x-axis, values on y) but with the count ascending to the left rather than the right
So the mirror image of this
iris %>%
  group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) -> histBar

ggplot(data = histBar,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                     y = count)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       coord_flip()


Any help much appreciated

Try scale_x_reverse. With coord_flip that should be scale_y_reverse.

Also, whenever you have both x and y coordinates, geom_col does what geom_bar does but with no need for stat = "identity".

If you reverse the axis sense the bars will still start at zero but now the zero is on the other side of the plot.
Other changes I have made are:

summarise has an argument .by, group_by is no longer needed;
whenever you have both x and y coordinates, geom_col does what geom_bar does but with no need for stat = "identity";
I have added a breaks argument since counts are integers, therefore, discrete.

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

iris %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .by = Sepal.Length) -> histBar

ggplot(data = histBar,
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:12)


Created on 2024-09-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Off-topic?
A plot going down just for fun.
iris %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .by = Sepal.Length) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:12)


Created on 2024-09-07 with reprex v2.1.0
And before the OP edit, the plot was a histogram.
ggplot(iris, mapping = aes(y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = 0:12)


Created on 2024-09-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Great answer @Rui Barradas. Sorry for the edit but colouring histograms with a colour palette is too hard. And you answered that anyway :)
